react-text-mask and Input ant.design
mask input does not work with input from antd.
maybe the ref needs to be transferred somehow in a different way.
export const MaskedInput = () => (
  <TextMask
    mask={[/\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/]}
    render={(textMaskRef, props) => (
      <Input
        {...props}
        ref={(inputRef) => {
          inputRef && textMaskRef(inputRef?.input);
        }}
      />
    )}
    placeholder={"4 numbers"}
  />
);

codesandbox
I tried to transfer the ref like this, but there was no effect
export const MaskedInput = React.memo(React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <TextMask
    mask={[/\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/]}
    render={(textMaskRef, props) => (
      <Input {...props}  ref={(inputRef) => {
        if (inputRef?.input) {
          textMaskRef(inputRef?.input);
          if (ref) {
            ref.current = inputRef?.input;
          }
        }
      }}
    />
    )}
  />
)));

